RISCV Syscalls In Ripes
I'm new to Ripes, I', trying to read input from the console, however, it keeps tell me that the value of a7 is 0.
This is my error
This is my code:
.text
main:
li a7, 1
ecall

Question: Did i do something wrong?
I tried every numbers for a7, but it keeps sending the same error message.

"I tried every number for a7" is not visible in your code. The code you shared does nothing with a7.

Yes, sorry, what i want to write is a7

.text
main:
li a7, 63
ecall
This still cause error

https://github.com/mortbopet/Ripes/blob/master/docs/ecalls.md <- 63 does not appear to be a valid call

I tried li a7, 1 also. Still the same error.

I don't think people will be able to make sense of the comments. Please [edit] your question with a representative piece of code and an error message that goes with that piece of code.

No idea what can be a problem here. I've literally copy and pasted the code shown here (as of now) into latest Ripes, both desktop and web version, and it did print 0 on console and shown no errors.
